# How to read mouse movement data using bash

Tags: bash, mouse

Is there a library which can be used to read mouse movement and to pass certain hotkey combinations or trigger certain files on certain movements?

I want to make functions which will be able to respond on these mouse movements like for example a three touch finger drag should trigger window spread.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `xdotool` command like so:

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

You can either use `watch xdotool getmouselocation` for interactive polling or if that's for bash script - write an infinite while loop.

```
while true
do
     xdotool getmouselocation
done
```